# Android - Compass in Precise View not working correctly in QField

Tags: qfield

I have a Pixel 7 Pro and a Pixel 6a Android phone. I get the following identical results with each phone.

When I select a feature in QField, and set the feature as destination, the compass in “Precise View” points in random directions. When I rotate my phone, the direction of North changes to a different direction that does not seem to be related to north or the orientation of my phone. The Bearing (to feature) is at the proper degrees on the compass, but because north on the compass does not point to north, the bearing points in the wrong direction. Therefore, I can not use Precise View to pinpoint the feature. Other compass applications on my phone work correctly. Is this a bug or have I missed a setting?

If I could lock the compass with north up, this would be an improvement. This is how QField works on my Windows laptop that does not have a compass. Is there a setting to lock north up?